# Aligning text under an image

Tags: html, css

I want to align some text under an image but the icon is on the left. Whenever I put a padding-left or right or margin to it it centers for one block but not for both. This is really annoying. You can see it on this screenshot: http://cl.ly/1G0D191t1G3V1v0a0K2q

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
  <link href="<?php echo base_url('css/style.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Admin :: Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="admin-form">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Admin Home</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content dashboard clearfix">
      <ul>
        <li><a href='<?php echo base_url('admin/DiveLocations');?>'><img src='<?php echo base_url('images/icons/duikplaats.png');?>'/>Duiklocaties</a></li>
        <li><a href='<?php echo base_url('admin/DiveEvents');?>'><img src='<?php echo base_url('images/icons/scubadiving.png');?>'/>Duiken</a></li>
        <li><a href='<?php echo base_url('admin/Users');?>'><img src='<?php echo base_url('images/icons/users.png');?>'/>Gebruikers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.dashboard img {
  display: block;
  margin-left:25px;
}

.dashboard ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case i would put the text within a `<span>` and the clear it:

```
.dashboard span {
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
```

I've done a fiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/JMEMc/

Comment: Thanks, I used a span before because I knew it could be accomplished with a span, my only mistake was that I put the span around the whole <img> and text